# How do you shun an IP automatically based on the number of current connections?

Tags: network, denial-of-service, cisco

If I have a single IP that's trying a Denial of Service attack, how can I automatically have it banned/shunned?  I go in and manually put it in a group of banned IP addresses, but I'd like for it to be done automatically, maybe if someone has 30 simultaneous connections.  Cisco ASA.

Comment: Perhaps use modsecurity (an open source WAF)

Comment: If you use Linux as the server you want to protect, check [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). That is in case you can't achieve it at your firewall (Cisco ASA) level.

Comment: fail2ban would not prevent from a DDoS scenario. It is primarily designed for limiting sequential attempts.

Comment: Do you need a sequence of CISCO IOS commands for an actual router, or are you doing something on a PC?  If PC which operating system.

Comment: @sandyp a single IP does not a DDoS make

Comment: Beware! Large organizations often use a single IP address for all the internal network. In that case it would not be a DDoS to have multiple connection from that IP. If you want to automate bans, you should considere having a white list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be possible using the ASAs threat-detection commands. For example using threat-detection you could setup scanning-threat and then use the shun command.

One implementation would be to create an object on the ASA that acts as a whitelist and then using threat-detection scanning-threat shun exception `insert whitelist group object name` you would be able to shun anything that is NOT in that whitelist. Please be aware that is not the exact syntax you will have to use the docs & `?` to find the exact commands however its mostly the correct syntax.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/113685-asa-threat-detection.html

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with just a Cisco ASA. It could be made possible with additional components like fail2ban calling the ASA CLI to manually shun or maybe via the API plugin.